# SQLite insert setting all id's to 0

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, sql-insert

Im using the following code to insert data into an SQLite bd:

```
public Alimento adicionarAlimentoBD(Alimento alimento) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(ID_ALIMENTO_API, alimento.getId_api());
values.put(ID_ALIMENTO_USER, alimento.getId_alimento_user());
values.put(NOME_ALIMENTO, alimento.getNome());
values.put(CALORIAS_ALIMENTO, alimento.getCalorias());
values.put(LIPIDOS_ALIMENTO, alimento.getLipidos());
values.put(CARBOIDRATOS_ALIMENTO, alimento.getCarboidratos());
values.put(PROTEINAS_ALIMENTO, alimento.getProteinas());

long id = this.database.insert(TABLE_NAME_ALIMENTO, null,values);

if (id > -1)
{
    alimento.setId(id);
    return alimento;
}
return null;
}
```

I want it to keep adding 1 to the ID but when I check my id's I get 0 from all fo them. If I make a sout of alimento.getId after "alimento.setId(id);" the id is as I want...

Table alimento:

```
String createAlimentoTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_ALIMENTO + "( " +
        ID_ALIMENTO + " INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY," +
        ID_ALIMENTO_API + " TEXT UNSIGNED," +
        ID_ALIMENTO_USER  + " TEXT UNSIGNED," +
        NOME_ALIMENTO + " TEXT UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
        CALORIAS_ALIMENTO + " INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
        LIPIDOS_ALIMENTO + " INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
        CARBOIDRATOS_ALIMENTO + " INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL," +
        PROTEINAS_ALIMENTO + " INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL )";
database.execSQL(createAlimentoTable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we see your table definition for Alimento? I suspect you have not set the field you want to increment as such. If it's just defined as an int it will default to zero unless you provide it some input.

For example, if the field is the primary key and you want to autoincrement try the following in your column definition

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```